# beginner hardware sniffing question

Tags: dumping, sniffing

this is not going to be a specific question but here goes.

Ive just started reading about reverse engineering for the 3ds. Is it possible to open the 3ds up and connect a probe somewhere on the chip and dump the RAM contents? Im looking for data on game mechanics etc.

Im new to this so I could have wrongly understood the process. If anyone could perhaps explain the process to me for a general system not a 3ds (if that is easier), what equipment I would need and what exactly I would need to do to dump the ram contents.

Also if there are any resources for beginners that you recommend can you post them here please?
I should say that I program in c and I am looking to learn reverse engineering as a hobby.

Comment: You may want to start with [Hacking the Xbox: An Introduction to Reverse Engineering](http://amzn.com/1593270291).